# Unity: The second touch should not work at all. How do I fix this error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an item that should follow the touch of a finger. But when I touch the screen for the second time and remove the first finger, the object immediately goes to the second finger.

Please see the picture for a complete description:

[image]

Immediately write that these lines of code don't work :

1.`if(Input.touchCount == 1)`

2.`Input.multiTouchEnabled = false;`

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
 private Vector3 _mOffset;
 private float _mZCoord;

 private void OnMouseDown()
 {    
    _mZCoord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
    _mOffset = gameObject.transform.position - GetMouseWorldPos();
 }
 private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPos()
 {
        var touchPointV2 = Input.GetTouch(0).position; 
        Vector3 touchPointV3 = new Vector3(touchPointV2.x, touchPointV2.y);
        touchPointV3.z = _mZCoord;
        return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPointV3);
 }

 void OnMouseDrag()
 {
    Debug.Log("Run  -  OnMouseDrag");
    transform.position = GetMouseWorldPos() + _mOffset;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is that for your second touch you again call `OnMouseDown` which **resets** the `_mOffset` and `_mzCoord` to new values according to the current (already moved) `transform.position`.

I think you would be better not using `OnMouseDown` at all but rather use the `touch.phase` cycle in `Update` .

Something like e.g.

```
public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 _mOffset;
    private float _mZCoord;

    private void Update ()
    {
        if(Input.touchCount < 1) return;

        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        switch(touch.phase)
        {
            case TouchPhase.Began:
                _mZCoord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
                _mOffset = gameObject.transform.position - GetMouseWorldPos(touch);
                break;

            case TouchPhase.Moved:
               transform.position = GetMouseWorldPos(touch) + _mOffset;
                break;
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPos(Touch touch)
    {
        // Note that Vector3 and Vector2 are implicitly convertible into each other
        Vector3 touchPoint = touch.position; 
        touchPoint.z = _mZCoord;
        return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPoint);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively if this still fails: Not sure but possible that a touchpad is not actually handled as touch but still as mouse input!

In this case I guess there is not much you can change except e.g. adding a counter/flag and not access touches at all like e.g.

```
public class DragDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 _mOffset;
    private float _mZCoord;

    private int touches;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {   
         touches++;

         if(touches != 1) return;

        _mZCoord = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position).z;
        _mOffset = gameObject.transform.position - GetMouseWorldPos();        
    }

    private void OnMouseUp()
    {
        touches--;
    }

    private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPos()
    {
        Vector3 touchPoint = Input.mousePosition; 
        touchPoint.z = _mZCoord;
        return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPoint);
    }

    void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        if(touches != 1) return;

        Debug.Log("Run  -  OnMouseDrag");
        transform.position = GetMouseWorldPos() + _mOffset;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer bro, but both methods don't work. I don't understand how to solve this. It may not be possible to do this on a smartphone.